# Customizing The "Not Found" Behavior of Laravel's Routing "Explicit Binding"

Tags: php, laravel, binding, model, routes

Here's the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding

The routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'u'], function () {
    Route::post('create', ['as' => 'createUser', 'uses' => 'UserController@create']);
    Route::get('{uuid}', ['as' => 'userDashboard', 'uses' => 'UserController@dashboard']);
});
```

The UserController.php:

```
public function dashboard(User $uuid)
{
    return View::make('user.dashboard');
}
```

Whenever the User isn't found in the database it throws these two exceptions:

```
2/2
NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103:
No query results for model [App\User].

1/2
ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 303:
No query results for model [App\User].
```

How do I customize the error? I want to redirect to the `createUser` route. The documentation instructs to pass a `Closure` as a third argument but I don't know how to do that with my current code.

**EDIT 1**

This is what I've tried so far without success:

```
   Route::model('{uuid}', ['as' => 'userDashboard', 'uses' => 'UserController@dashboard'], function () {
        App::abort(403, 'Test.');
    });

   Route::get('{uuid}', ['as' => 'userDashboard', 'uses' => 'UserController@dashboard'], function () {
        App::abort(403, 'Test.');
    });
```

Comment: are you in debug mode? here the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Comment: @ClearBoth Yes. What I want to do is redirect to another page instead of showing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually very simple. As none of the answers really give a definite answer I am answering it myself.

In the file `RouteServiceController.php`'s `boot` function add the following:

```
    $router->model('advertiser', 'App\Advertiser', function () {
        throw new AdvertiserNotFoundException;
    });
```

Then create a new empty class in `App\Exceptions` called (in this case) `AdvertiserNotFoundException.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class AdvertiserNotFoundException extends Exception
{

}
```

The last thing to do is to catch the exception in the `Handler.php`'s `render` function (`App\Exception`) like so:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    switch ($e)
    {
        case ($e instanceof AdvertiserNotFoundException):
            //Implement your behavior here (redirect, etc...)
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

That's it! :)

Answer (score 1):

for a similar case i did,
I took the parent `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler isHttpException` function and copied it to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and changed it's name to my `isUserNotFoundException`.

```
protected function isUserNotFoundException(Exception $e)
{
    return $e instanceof UserNotFoundException;
}
```

and than in the render function add

```
  if ($this->isUserNotFoundException($e))
       return redirect('path')->with('error',"Your error message goes here");
```

Following code must be placed in your RouteServiceProvider::boot method

```
$router->model('uuid', 'App\User', function () {
throw new UserNotFoundException;
```

});

and make sure to include this in your view file

and this forum post might help you

```
https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-laravel-404-page-using-custom-exception-handlers
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you make the `->with()` (flash session) work? I have tried everything and it simply doesn't work.

Comment: please check the modified line for redirect, and yes make sure to include '{{ session('error') }}' error in blade template

Comment: I can't make the flash session work, please check my other question if you would be so kind: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553083/laravel-5-2-flash-session-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

To do so you need to check if the id exist in the model like so:

```
public function dashboard(User $uuid)
{
    if(User::find($uuid))
    {
        return View::make('user.dashboard');
    } else {
        redirect('xyz');
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't even start the function if the argument passed isn't found in the specified Model's (`User`) database table.

Comment: hmmm.. I see so the best way is to go with middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the exception and treat in in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if (!env('APP_DEBUG')) {      
        if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
            //treat error
            return response()->view('errors.404');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

**Edit 1:**
This piece of code is from a working project so if this doesn't work it must have an error somewhere else:

```
if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
    $data= \App\Data::orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();                              
    return response()->view('errors.404', [
        'data' => $data                  
    ], 404);
}
```

**Edit 2:**
You can use the above code and [this tutorial](https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/category/handling-exceptions-and-custom-exceptions-laravel-5-1/) in order to create a new Exception type in order to get your desired behavior. To my understanding at least. :)

Comment: How do I customize different errors for different Models/Routes? In this case I want to redirect to the User creation page but in other implementation I might want to redirect to a different page. Your method will apply the same rule for every `ModelNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial will be helpful for you [Laravel Model Binding](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/implicit-model-binding-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: It shows pretty much the same this as the documentation. [This](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/implicit-model-binding-in-laravel-5-2#custom-exceptions-for-route-model-binding) is the part I'm interested in but can't figure out how to use it with controllers. I'm passing the third argument but it does nothing.