# Laravel 5.2 Flash Session Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect, routes

Here's my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('advertise', ['as' => 'advertise', 'uses' => 'AdvertiseController@index']);
```

Here's the relevant part of the `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    switch ($e)
    {
        case ($e instanceof AdvertiserNotFoundException):
            return redirect()->route('advertise')->with('status', 'Advertiser not found.');
        default:
            return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm (trying to) display the message:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

It is correctly catching the `AdvertiserNotFoundException` and redirecting to the route `advertise` but the response isn't carrying any flash data.

I'm not including the web middleware as all routes are covered by it by default.

**EDIT 1**

Here's the error log if it helps:

```
[2016-07-24 14:31:59] local.ERROR: exception 'App\Exceptions\AdvertiserNotFoundException' in C:\MyApp\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php:31 Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}('12d5763b-2a16-4...')
#1 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1003): call_user_func(Object(Closure), '12d5763b-2a16-4...')
#2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}('12d5763b-2a16-4...', Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#3 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(885): call_user_func(Object(Closure), '12d5763b-2a16-4...', Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#4 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(838): Illuminate\Routing\Router->performBinding('advertiser', '12d5763b-2a16-4...', Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#5 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(825): Illuminate\Routing\Router->substituteBindings(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#6 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(691): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(136): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 C:\MyApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\MyApp\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

`with()` function is used pass data from controller to a view.

You need to set the data using session as follows:

```
case ($e instanceof AdvertiserNotFoundException):
    session('status', 'Advertiser not found.');
    return redirect()->route('advertise');
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work, the session is empty.

Comment: what's your Laravel version?

Comment: for set new key in session you must pass associative array to session function like this:   `session(['key' => 'value'])` 
your written code returns 'Advertiser not found.' if session has not `status` key