# How to treat 'No query results for model' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

We have a DB with 100 users.. for example

And here is the route

```
Route::get('/users/{user}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
```

Here is the method

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    $hi = 'Hello';
    return $hi;
}
```

Ok.. if I do something like this

```
http://localhost/users/99/edit | WORKS
http://localhost/users/100/edit | WORKS
http://localhost/users/101/edit | PROBLEM
```

How to solve when the user change the value from URL with an inexistent record..?

Comment: This is because the user with the id 101 does not exist, you can pass the id and use `find` method in a try block and on exception redirect

Comment: Redirect to 404 page

Comment: That's the correct behaviour of laravel, you just need to create Handler to render a 404 page.

Comment: @ka_lin I know does not exist..just want a method...cause if i'm using $user without 'User' the model...everything it's ok..all I have to do is to make some cheks..but I want to keep the version with Model

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva and how can I do that?

Comment: @clotilda see this url to [render 404 page](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-laravel-404-page-using-custom-exception-handlers)

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would pass the user id as a parameter rather than explicit binding:

`Route::get('/users/{userId}/edit', 'UserController@edit');`

When a model is not found you will get a `ModelNotFoundException` exception thrown, you can catch it and treat this case

Controller:

```
use Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/ModelNotFoundException;

[...]

public function edit($userId)
    {
        try{
            $user = User::find($userId);
            //do some stuff
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e){
            //treat error (log the activity, redirect to a certain page)
            //or display a 404 page
            //dealer's choice
        }
    }
```

Comment: Laravel is implicitly doing the same thing...you're eventually throwing Exception that is already being thrown and OP wants to actually handle that.

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva Laravel does return a http status code of 404(with html), I have also pointed out the OP can do various other things, don't you agree?

Comment: I do agree... your answer is a viable solution but having a single handler to render a 404 page would make it more generic.

Comment: It was merely an example, maybe I haven't made it clearer

Comment: Thanks for response..but I want to use with the model name.. edit( User $user)

Comment: You either use DeepanshSachdeva`s solution (article link) or mine from what I can tell.
You need to change the route definition either way, why can't you?

Comment: @ka_lin i'm using in a lot of methods ..so I don't have so much time..is a big project..and I can't do all the things to solve the new changes.. Why I need to change route definition if i'm using DeepanshSachdeva method..?

Comment: @clotilda: Have you even read the article? I believe not because the article states that a solution would be to inject an exception in the controller's method (which I do not like but seems to work). Even if it's a big project it needs to evolve, change is imminent

Comment: @ka_lin but i'm looking in something like this if it is possible. When for example I'm calling /users/50000/edit ..if this user don't exist..to redirect on /users page..not on a 404.

Comment: Any good solution requires you to change the controller, period

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546143/customizing-the-not-found-behavior-of-laravels-routing-explicit-binding

Answer (score 0):

In your case the user can't be found, which is a 404:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    $user = false; // dummy/example
    if ($user) {
        return $your_results;
    } else {
        return view('errors.404');
        // assuming you have a folder called 'errors' inside your 'views' folder
        // and the file name is `404.blade.php`
        // and are using blade files.
    }        
}
```

If the user can be found, show whatever you need to, else,  show a 404 blade view.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but it is an useful question.

To suppress the error message you can set the debug mode in the (dot)ENV file to false `APP_DEBUG=true`. Due to the route model binding, the other solutions above won't help you, because if the model is not found, you won't get into the controller. Unless you don't get the model but only the id or slug etc. and then make a query against the database within the function.